# How do you pick date, hour minute from jquery datetimepick function

Tags: jquery

I need to use jquery datetime picker to pick date and hour minute from the calendar.

Here is the jsfiddle: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/manikoth/Fa8Xx/)

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

It picks date but no hour and minute, any ideas I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) jQuery addon

```
$('#basic_example_1').datetimepicker();
```

Comment: I've added the timepicker adon, I see milliseconds,seconds, timezone etc in the calendar image. How could I just limit it to hour and minute?

Comment: not sure what the problem is but, looks like I have to include all of these js libraries to make it work and then I still see ms, seconds etc:<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>